# Highcharts - sorting JSON data JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, highcharts

I've been having trouble sorting my data for my `Highcharts` line chart. When one array is used (Today) the graph appears normal. But we have a secondary "Yesterday" data button that is suppose to concat the two arrays together into one chart.

I have a sorting function and I can't seem to get the data to appear correctly.

45 Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15

**Code**

```
function paintChart(){
    var yesterdayEnabled = $('#showYesterday').is(':checked');
    $.each(chart.series, function(i,s) {
        var flowObj = inFlowObj;
        if(view === 'ex'){
            flowObj = exFlowObj;
        }
        thisZone = s.options.id;
        var allData = flowObj[thisZone].flow;
        if(yesterdayEnabled){
            allData = allData.concat(flowObj[thisZone].yestFlow);
            allData.sort(custom_sort);
        }

        s.setData(allData); 
    });
}

function custom_sort(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.timeStamp).getTime() - new Date(b.timeStamp).getTime();
}
```

I've tried sorting the data in the `setData` function and defining it in the `series: seriesData.sort(custom_sort)` to no avail.
Is there a different way to sort this data?

**Error**
[image]

**Example Data**

Yesterday -

```
{"status":"success","count":3384,"data":[{"timeStamp":"2016-06-13T04:00:00Z","interface":"mid","id":23,"up":2292.61,"pos":2450.0,"neg":-9999.0},...
```

Today

```
{"status":"success","count":3384,"data":[{"timeStamp":"2016-06-14T04:00:00Z","interface":"mid","id":23,"up":2029.31,"pos":2550.0,"neg":-9999.0},...
```

Comment: return new Date(a.timeStamp).getTime() - new Date(b.timeStamp).getTime();   has problem

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi I got this from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort2.shtml)

Comment: Do you have both of your series sorted before you will convert them into one array? If yes, I think you don't need sorting method at all, you can simply make new data array and inside this array push yesterday data and then today data. Here you can see example similar to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/0qwbtwax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a suggestion, I created a modified `paintChart()` function which pushes the data in the array in the correct order:

```
function paintChart(){
    var yesterdayEnabled = $('#showYesterday').is(':checked');
    $.each(chart.series, function(i,s) {
        var flowObj = inFlowObj;
        if(view === 'ex'){
            flowObj = exFlowObj;
        }
        thisZone = s.options.id;
        var allData = flowObj[thisZone].flow;
        var addYestData = [];
        if(yesterdayEnabled){
            Highcharts.each(flowObj[thisZone].yestFlow, function(p, i) {
                addYestData.push(p);
            })
            Highcharts.each(flowObj[thisZone].flow, function(p, i) {
                addYestData.push(p);
            })

            s.setData(addYestData);
        } else{
            s.setData(allData);
        }


    });
}
```